# Copy text to input field on page load using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to copy text `This is Sparta` into the input field on page load. I'm wondering how to go about this using jQuery or Javascript.

```
<p id="addTag">This is Sparta</p>
<input name="showTag" type="text" id="showTag" />
```

Anyone?

Comment: Why not just put it in the markup as the `value` parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using vanilla JavaScript:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  document.getElementById('showTag').value = document.getElementById('addTag').textContent;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="addTag">This is Sparta</p>
<input name="showTag" type="text" id="showTag" />
```

**Using jQuery:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#showTag').val($('#addTag').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="addTag">This is Sparta</p>
<input name="showTag" type="text" id="showTag" />
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much. I got it working using Umair's solution.

Comment: @ElaineByene, if the value is plain text then it is better to use `text()` instead of `html()`

Answer (score 1):

JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#showTag').val($('#addTag').html());
});
```